# For loop inside if statement, getting skipped

Tags: python

When i run my code with a number between 2 and 12, the result asked for doesnt show up, but the elif does work. So im stumped on how to solve this. and my teacher wants me to include an if statement.

Ive already tried to look for ways to use this if statement differently,  but ive ended up confused.

```py
tt = int(input("What times tables would you like: "))
if 2 >= tt >= 12:
    for x in range(1, 13):
        aw = tt * x
        print(tt, "x", x, " = ", aw)
elif tt < 2 or tt > 12:
    print("Please enter number between 2 and 12")
```

The expected is printed times tables of the input number

Comment: 2 is not greater than 12, so the condition will always be False... Did you mean `2 <= tt <=  12`?

Answer (score 3):

This is the wrong way round and can never be true, because you're asking for `tt` to be less than 2 and at least 12 at the same time:

```
if 2 >= tt >= 12:
```

You probably meant:

```
if 2 <= tt <= 12:
```

And instead of `elif` with a condition, you can just use `else`.

Comment: ohhh ok im dumb thank you

Answer (score 0):

That is.

```
    tt = int(input("What times tables would you like: "))
    if 2 <= tt <= 12:
        for x in range(1, 13):
            aw = tt * x
            print(tt, "x", x, " = ", aw)
    else:
        print("Please enter number between 2 and 12")
```

Comment: thanks for the help